# Can we create a Flash File and use that through VBS to run it on Startup

Tags: windows, flash, vbscript, startup

Can we create a Flash File and use that through VBS to run it on Startup. Actually I wanted to make a Flash while which takes Voice Commands as Password and  checks for the match. Then alows me to login to Windows. I got to know that we can do that Startup process and all through VBS but dont know how to call a Flash file thorugh the VBS and run it thorugh .vbs file itself. So need help there to call that file and run it there. Any one please help here.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need some 3th party ActiveX library to create Flash files with VBScript.

I'm aware of only two (commercial):

- [SWF Scout SDK](http://www.delphiflash.com/swfscout_example_vbscript)
- [Active Server Flash](http://www.emarksoft.com/asp-flash-vbscript-CreatePolygon.htm)